# Can't add more than one element to the content view

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios13, macos-catalina

As the title says. Whenever I add more than one text element into the content view, my canvas will fail to build and my body variable initializing closure returns this error: "Function declares an opaque return type, but has no return statements in its body from which to infer an underlying type"

I thought the issue was that I was on Mojave, when the canvas wasn't even showing up and the same error occurred. However I have updated to Catalina and am still getting the error.

I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use types like List, Group, VStack, ... to wrap your content. You can't have two raw Text elements in your content view. Example using Group:

```
var body: some View {
  Group {
    Text("1")
    Text("2")
  }
}
```